# How to update Datamodel in RecyclerviewAdapter

Tags: java, android

i created a recyclerview where i can see all my chats. Every item contains the name, the lastmessage and a thumb. if the user send or receive a new message, it should be displayed there and the item should go to position 0. Now i have the problem that the message is displayed, but the chat item goes only to the first position if the position was not 0 before. So if i receive two new messages its not working anymore because the data model is the same like before. So how can i fit my data model to the current position of every item. Currently my adapter looks like this:

```
private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";
private Context context;
private Activity mActivity;
private List<MatchesObject> matchesList;
private String currentUid;

public matchadapterino(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<MatchesObject> mDataSet) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
    this.matchesList = mDataSet;


}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public matchadapterino.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view.
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.matchesitem, viewGroup, false);

    return new matchadapterino.ViewHolder(v);
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final matchadapterino.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.getMatchname().setText(matchesList.get(position).getUsername());

    if (!matchesList.get(position).getProfileImageUrl().equals("default")) {
        Picasso.with(mActivity).load(matchesList.get(position).getProfileImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.getMatchImage());
        getLastMSG(matchesList.get(position).getUserId(), viewHolder.getLastMSG(), position);
        viewHolder.getMatchImage().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, UserDetailView.class);
                //
                i.putExtra("userId", matchesList.get(position).getUserId());
                mActivity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    } else {
        viewHolder.getMatchImage().setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    }
    viewHolder.getForeground().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, Chat.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();


            b.putString("matchId", matchesList.get(position).getUserId());
            i.putExtras(b);
            mActivity.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return matchesList.size();
}


// Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the contents of the view
// with that element

public void removeItem(int position) {
    matchesList.remove(matchesList.get(position));
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)

/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
 */    
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {    
    public TextView matchname, lastMSG;    
    public ImageView matchImage;    
    private RelativeLayout foreground;
    private RelativeLayout background;


    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        currentUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();


        matchname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.matchname);
        matchImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.matchImages);
        lastMSG = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastmsg);
        foreground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foregroundmatch);
        background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundmatch);
    }

    public RelativeLayout getForeground() {
        return foreground;
    }

    public RelativeLayout getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public TextView getLastMSG() {
        return lastMSG;
    }


    public TextView getMatchname() {
        return matchname;
    }

    public ImageView getMatchImage() {
        return matchImage;
    }


}

private void getLastMSG(final String userId, final TextView lastMSG, final int position) {
    final String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("connections").child("matches").child(userId);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


                notifyItemMoved(0, position);


                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "position changed" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (dataSnapshot.child("lastMsgBy").getValue().toString().equals(userid)) {


                    lastMSG.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d2403a3a"));
                    String lastMsg = dataSnapshot.child("lastMsg").getValue().toString();
                    lastMSG.setText(lastMsg);
                } else {

                    lastMSG.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                    String lastMsg = dataSnapshot.child("lastMsg").getValue().toString();
                    lastMSG.setText(lastMsg);


                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You should move your `Firebase` query from `onBindViewHolder` as it can produce unexpected results. Query before initializing the `RecyclerView` and pass the data as `List`

Comment: thats no good idea because i need to reload the whole list every time

Comment: The method `onBindViewHolder` gets called everytime you scroll. A new item is created by `recyclerview`. That mean it will be called multiple times when ever you scroll

Comment: and how would you solve it